# Why teleportation doesn't work right?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to recreate portal scene using 
[**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHqjscifPnI) video. The link to the scene assets and scripts is under the video.

I'm facing a **problem with teleportation**:

The player should walk through a plane-trigger in the portal to be moved to the location of the second portal. But it seems to me that after teleportation, he appears in the middle of plane-trigger in the second portal. And if he continues moving, he jumps back to the first portal, and then again to the second portal and so on.

Why is it happening and how can it be fixed? As I understand the author of the script, it should teleport player after passing through the trigger, but the script doesn't work like that for me.

Here is the script for teleportation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Sender : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject receiver;

    private float prevDot = 0;
    private bool playerOverlapping = false;

    void Start () {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (playerOverlapping) {
            var currentDot = Vector3.Dot(transform.up, player.transform.position - transform.position);

            if (currentDot < 10) // only transport the player once he's moved across plane
            {
                // transport him to the equivalent position in the other portal
                float rotDiff = -Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, receiver.transform.rotation);
                rotDiff += 180;
                player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotDiff);

                Vector3 positionOffset = player.transform.position - transform.position;
                positionOffset = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotDiff, 0) * positionOffset;
                var newPosition = receiver.transform.position + positionOffset;
                player.transform.position = newPosition;

                playerOverlapping = false;
            }

            prevDot = currentDot;
        }
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerOverlapping = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerOverlapping = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this would be to simply increase the offset of the player's position when teleported, but then you won't achieve the desired smooth transition.

The other method I thought of would be to add a public boolean variable to the Sender script (I'm assuming that the Sender script is on all portals), with a default value of false.
When you teleport, you set the player's position to the new position using the receiving teleporter's position. Because you have access to the receiving teleporter GameObject, you could use GetComponent to get it's Sender script. You could then set this boolean variable to true before teleporting the player.
Once the player is teleported, the OnTriggerEnter method is automatically invoked, which is your problem. You could put an if statement in OnTriggerEnter so that when it was activated, it would only teleport IF the boolean variable was false. Because it's true when the player teleports, you aren't allowed to teleport back until you leave the portal trigger, then you could set the boolean variable back to false. This would mean that the normal behavior of walking through a portal is unaffected, because the default boolean value is false.

Also, this code would probably be much better if you had your actual teleportation in OnTriggerEnter instead of Update, as Absinthe said.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this way, but looks like this is what I need!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you're going with your original code (no pun intended) and I didn't watch through the video (TLDR) but you'll need to rethink this from scratch. Using the Update method is totally inappropriate; update fires on every frame - you want to teleport every frame?

Instead use the OnTriggerEnter method:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
   other.transform.position = theVectorYouWantToTeleportTo
}
```

Comment: thank you, the problem is that I'm trying to achieve a seamless transition, when user see rendered image from the second camera in the second scene, and in the next moment he teleports to the same position in the second scene, so it looks like he just walk through the portal like through the door. The problem is that in this case user will appear in the middle of collider in the second portal, which will also use OnTriggerEnter method to teleport player back. This way the player will never walk through the portal.

Comment: You could set a 'teleportedAlready' boolean variable on the player, teleporter or some global object to prevent the player being teleported back right away. You could use a coroutine to reset the variable after a certain amount of time if you wanted the 2nd teleported to be useable again.

Comment: Thank you, this is also an interesting option! But in this case, if the player will stay near the portal for some time while touching its trigger, he will teleport back again after coroutine time ends.

Comment: So use OnTriggerExit to start the coroutine. There's lots of ways to do things :)